# Programmatically sort and export data from a file with Perl

Tags: perl, csv, text-files, large-files

I have a massive text file, with terrible formatting that I am trying to convert into a clean CSV.

I am trying to anchor `Firstname`, `Lastname`, `Email`, `Phone`, `IP`, `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15` and `16` as column headers.

Some of the data set has not filled out questions 1-16 so they are null.

The unique problem I am having, while looping through the data is, if the person filled out questions 1-16 they are displayed *before* the customer data, and I am at a loss at how to append the questions *after* the customer data properly, as well as starting a new row when the text `"firstname"`, `"lastname"`, `"email"` or `"phone"` are present but `1-16` are not.

This is an example of the current data

```
1.  No,
2.   No,
3.  Yes,
4.  No,
5.  Yes,
6.  No,
7.  Yes,
8.  Yes,
9. Yes,
10.  Yes,
11.  Yes,
12. No,
13.  No,
14.  No,
15.  Yes,
16.  Yes,


Firstname: xxx
Lastname: xxx
Email: xxx@xxx.com
Phone: xxxxxxxxxx
IP Address: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

Firstname: xxx
Lastname: xxx
Email: xxx@xxx.net
Phone: xxxxxxxxxx
IP Address: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

The desired output would export to a new CSV file, like this

```
Firstname, Lastname, Email, Phone, IP Address,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16
xxx,xxx,xxx@xxx.com,xxxxxxxxxx,xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx,no,no,yes,no,yes,no,yes,yes,yes,yes,yes,no,no,no,yes,yes
xxx,xxx,xxx@xxx.net,xxxxxxxxxx,xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,`
```

I hope I am getting somewhere close by using this code here

```
#!usr/bin/perl

open my $fh, "<", "splits.txt";

my %record = {};
while (<$fh>) {
  if ($_ =~ /\d+\.\s*(Yes,|No,)/) {
    add_field_to_record($_, %record);
  }
  if (/^IP Address:/) {
    output_as_csv(%record);
    %record = {};
  }
}

output_as_csv(%record);

open(MYFILE, '>>data.csv');
print MYFILE %record;
close(MYFILE);
```

UPDATE: there are always 16 questions however further down the file, they are not labeled with numbers but have a YES or NO following a question mark (?), example:

```
Do you have a plan for dealing with waste if the water is cut off and the toilet can't be flushed? No
Do you have a battery-operated or wind-up radio to use for information and updates if the electricity goes out? No
Do you have back up-batteries for powered devices (tools, cell phone, flashlight, radio, etc.) in the case of a power outage? No
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest something like this. It keeps a hash of all the data found so far, and dumps the contents to the output file when the key just found matches the last of the named data fields.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $fh,  '<', 'splits.txt' or die qq{Unable to open "splits.txt" for input: $!};
open my $out, '>', 'data.csv'   or die qq{Unable to open "data.csv" for output: $!};

my @fields = ('Firstname', 'Lastname', 'Email', 'Phone', 'IP Address');

print $out join(',', @fields, 1..16), "\n"; # Print the header

my %data;

while (<$fh>) {

  next unless /\S/;

  if (/ ^ (\d+) \. \s+ (Yes|No) /x ) {
    $data{$1} = lc $2;
  }
  elsif (/ ^ ([^:]+) : \s+ (.+) /x) {
    $data{$1} = $2;
    if ($1 eq $fields[-1] ) {
      print $out join(',', map $data{$_} // '', @fields, 1..16), "\n";
      %data = ();
    }
  }
}
```

**output**

```
Firstname,Lastname,Email,Phone,IP Address,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16
xxx,xxx,xxx@xxx.com,xxxxxxxxxx,xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx,no,no,yes,no,yes,no,yes,yes,yes,yes,yes,no,no,no,yes,yes
xxx,xxx,xxx@xxx.net,xxxxxxxxxx,xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

Comment: Search pattern not terminated at line 23., no idea what that means!

Comment: @user3547033 It means you're using Perl 5.8 or older...you need to upgrade! (Perl 5.10 was released in 2007!)

Comment: @user3547033 As a workaround that changes Borodin's solution minimally, you can replace the line `print $out join(',', map $data{$_} // '', @fields, 1..16), "\n";` with `print $out join(',', map(defined $data{$_} ? $data{$_} : '', @fields, 1..16)), "\n";`

Comment: I have upgraded and the script is working!  however after running I have found that some of the data is not formatted in the same way, I have updated the question, any ideas or input greatly appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

```
my %record = {};
while(<>) {
  add_field_to_record($_, %record);
  if (/^IP Address:/) {
    output_as_csv(%record);
    %record = {};
  }
}
```

Your title says "sorting" but the description doesn't mention it, so not sure what you meant by it. `output_as_csv` and `add_field_to_record` should be trivial.

EDIT: the last line was too much.

Comment: sorry, perl noobie here, is http://pastebin.com/7FTNjHVs getting anywhere close to what I need?

Comment: Not quite, your reading/writing logic is off, and the two parts that I left for you to implement are still unimplemented :) In particular, `<>` reads from stdin, your `$fin` is unused, and `$str` was never created.

Comment: could you please elaborate?  if you see http://pastebin.com/wM5NT4bA maybe I am getting closer?  IO am opting the file, reading the file line by line, looking for yesor no, and trying to add the feild to eh record, then run a check for ip address for the 2nd block of text and then trying to output into a .txt file

any help is greatly appreciated!  Thanks!

Comment: You clearly haven't tested your solution. `use strict` and `use warnings` are *essential* for any new Perl code, and if you were to use them in your solution it would die with something like `Reference found where even-sized list expected`. You are also passing a list of the keys and values in `%record` to both subroutines, so they have no way of writing to the hash.

Comment: @Borodin: Wasn't a solution, but Perlish pseudocode, to show the general algorithm - so yeah, I did not test it.